# Get stuck when I download stock info to R

Tags: r, list, time-series, stock

I was trying to download some stock information to R.

Normally, I use the code `getSymbols()`. However, this time, because of the location, the speed is super slow and I failed a lot. So I use another code `md_stock()`, then the problem came in.

The minimal reproducible example:

```
# Step1: 
library(pedquant)
# Step2: 
tickers = c('000858', '600887', '000651', '600176')
# Step3: 
port = md_stock(tickers, from = "2003-01-01", source = "163")
# Step4: 
stock1 = xts(port[["000858"]], port[["000858"]][["date"]])[,7]
# Step5: 
ROC(stock1, type = "discrete")
```

I can't execute the `ROC` command. When I looked deeper, I found the price in time-series data "stock1" are all character. I don't know how to fix it. I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Difficult to help you. Please make sure you provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Maybe: step 1: `data1 <- port[[1]]` followed by 
step 2: `data1 <- data1[, c("date", "close")] `.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated an example.

Comment: Earlier your problem was how to extract dfs from the list object `port`. You provided a picture showing your environment -> data -> `port`. Now it is about `ROC()`, this command wasn't element of your initial question. Also, I don't understand the syntax `xts(..)`. Cannot follow you.

Comment: Thank you again. I just tried to make the question more simple this time. My final goal is to have useful data so I can make some calculations. In other words, how to download data from the code "md_stock" and then transform it to normal time-series data, to which I can execute code like "ROC". The "xts(..)" part comes from an instruction by R. After executing the first three steps, I got a list including all the information. If I open the list and click the contents inside, R shows me the corresponding code. For example, when I click date index, R shows me "port[["000858"]][["date"]]"

Comment: Please make it easy to copy.  Remove Step1, Step2 since no one can easily copy the code and paste it into their session with those tags interfering.  If you want to number the lines add a comment at the end of the line such as `#1`, `#2`, etc. although I don't really think that numbering is really needed.